# SummerNote => getting back text content

Tags: php, rich-text-editor, summernote

I'm trying to use SummerNote to be able to create rich text articles, store them in mysql db , and then pull the different articles when requested .. i'm using php

I'm able to store the texts in my db, but I really don't understand how to pull the content back to a page ..
I mean , the texts are saved like :

```
&lt;h1 dir=&quot;ltr&quot; id=&quot;docs-internal-guid-142f6dfb-7fff-ab05-e1c4-d1ffb14fd8d7&quot;
style=&quot;caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 20pt
```

How do I call , decoded, the content ?
I went through https://summernote.org/getting-started/ many times and I don't get how to do it ..
If someone can just point me where to look .. I would be very grateful
thanks in advance

Comment: You may be looking for [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) or [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode). I'm completely unfamiliar with Summernote specifically though, just giving you general pointers.

Comment: html_entity_decode did the job !